# select 100 records in range

Tags: sql, t-sql

Lets say I have a student table and there are 1000 records in it.

I would like to write such a query that should select only 100 records but I should be able to define the range.

```
Ex. 100 records showing from 501 to 600
or 100 records showing from 101 to 200
```

P.S. Yes! There is a identity column but it consists of random numbers.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: how do you define the range ? There should be some column that defines it, you can't just ask for number 501-600 record without defining the record number

Comment: I count the new column named RowNum so that I know how many records I have then I give the range.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it.

```
SELECT a.* FROM (
     SELECT Row_Number() OVER(ORDER BY table.MySortCol) as RowNum,
     table.* -- columns you need
     FROM table
) a
WHERE a.RowNum between 1 and 100
```

This will give you a consistent result set even if you don't have a sequential id on the table, so you can perform meaningful paging or what have you.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without specifying a sort order?

Answer (score 1):

use **[`TOP`<sup>[docs]</sup>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx)** for SQL Server

```
SELECT TOP 100 *
FROM tableName
WHERE columnName BETWEEN 0 AND 100
```

but in `LIMIT` for MySQL

```
SELECT *
FROM tableName
WHERE col BETWEEN 0 AND 100
LIMIT 100
```

**UPDATE 1**

```
WITH sampleRec
AS
(
    SELECT column1, col2, col3,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY colName) rn
    FROM yourTableName
)
SELECT column1, col2, col3
FROM sampleRec
WHERE rn BETWEEN 1 AND 100
```

Comment: but I don't have any column goes from 1 to 100 so in this case I should be selecting row 1 to row 100. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: can you show even a little sample records? wait i'll update the answer using `CTE`

Comment: The Row_number creates an int field that gives you a 1 to n sequential field you can filter by.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MySQL use the LIMIT command.

SELECT * FROM MyTable LIMIT X, Y

Where X is your start record and Y is the number of records.
So for your 501 to 600 you'd do LIMIT 501, 100.

This probably works in other SQL versions - just look up the LIMIT command for your system.

Comment: @JTC - The tsql tag was not there originally... just sql.

Comment: darren answered the question before it was added `TSQL` tag.

Comment: Ah. Was there when I came here. mb